# Priority redirecting using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to set a priority in my `.htaccess`.

Ok, I've got folders on my root project, schema:

```
-root:
  -core
  -includes
  -pages:
     - profile.php
     -etc
  -support
  -infractions
  -.htaccess
```

and what I want to do is:
If the URL is like `https://example.com/support`, show the `/support/index.php`.
I've tried `-Indexes` option but it doesn't works or doesn't meet my needs.

My `.htaccess` is like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +Indexes
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fenixcms\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fenixcms.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /

DirectoryIndex pages/index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^alert/([^/\.]+)/?$ pages/alert.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^player/([^/\.]+)/?$ pages/profile.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/new_topic/([^/\.]+)/?$ /forums/new_topic.php?c=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/topics/([^/\.]+)/posts/edit/([^/\.]+)/?$ /forums/edit_post.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/topics/([^/\.]+)/posts/new/?$ /forums/new_post.php?tid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/topics/([^/\.]+)/posts/reply_to_id/([^/\.]+)/?$ /forums/new_quote.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/topics/([^/\.]+)/edit/?$ /forums/edit_topic.php?tid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/topics/([^/\.]+)/?$ /forums/topic.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/topics/([^/\.]+)/posts/delete/([^/\.]+)/?$ /forums/delete_post.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/categories/([^/\.]+)/?$ /forums/categories.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/posts/([^/\.]+)/?$ /forums/posts.php?pid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/\.]+)/?$ /forums/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^revisions/([^/\.]+)/?$ pages/revisions.php?action=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ /$1/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ pages/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @anubhava but my index page is on the pages folder

Comment: @anubhava please read the question again :), and changing my DirectoryIndex doesn't change anyting about my question